# How to display P0 and Pn-1

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How can I display the index of P0 has a small letter, as well as Pn-1 (where the n-1 is small) ?

I know it's a simple thing but i'm starting with latex and not being able to hit the correct keywords on google.

Comment: If you're starting out, you may find Tobias Oetiker's [Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX 2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort) or one of its translations to be worth reading. This particular question is covered in section 3.3 of that document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Math mode

In LaTeX (and TeX) the subscript is represented by an underscore `_` and *only* available in **math mode**. If only one charcacter follows you can type `_x` if there are more characters in the subscript, you must use braces `_{xyz}`.

There are two styles of math:
**Inline math**, shown with dollar sings `$...$` or with `\(...\)`*,

```
Soe if we say $P_0$ and $P_{n-1}$ are stupid, we can assume that ...
```

and **display style math**, which could come in several ways, e.g.

```
Now we se that
   \[P_0 = p_{n-1}\]
and guess that ...
```

To write text like indices in math mode it’s recommended to use `\text` from the `amsmath` package (or via `mathtools`), e.g.

```
Assuming that ... $x_\text{min}=0$ ...
```

<sub>* The dollar sings `$` are the old TeX syntax but work with LaTeX. The parenthesis version `\( \)` only works with LaTeX.</sub>

### Text mode

For the **text mode** there is only a `\textsuperscript{text}`. With KOMA-Script you will also get `\textsubscript{text}`.

---

**I strongly recommend that you read some LaTeX guides to learn the basics. See [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex) or consult you local book dealer.**

Comment: The KOMA-classes also provide a `\textsubscript{<sub>}`.

Comment: @cgnieder: Thanks, I know. I added it after posting a first short answer :-)